# What do companies like Apple do to make their software feel natural, cohesive, and refined?

Tags: graphic-design, emotion, lookandfeel

**From a UX standpoint, is there anything governing how a program/mobile app subconsciously makes the user feel? How do users end up getting the feeling that products are solid, secure, and integrated?**

I'm working with 4 different programs that are going to be marketed as an integrated ecosystem. This includes a console on the physical unit, a thin client that has the exact same feature set as the console, a thin clients that's supposed to "feel" like the thin client with more features, a web based management system, and a mobile app.

Beyond the obvious, which is making all look and behave similarly, I want it all to feel refined and bug free, but I want to tell the graphic designer to do more than "make it all look the same". **It needs to make the user feel like what they're doing is private, reliable, and secure (the app deals with highly sensitive data).**

A prime example of this for me is Apple: A lot of people *feel* like their products are all a part of the same package, feel solid, and feel bug free. It's such an abstract feeling, but I'm sure there's a lot behind it.

I could make similar comments regarding facebook: When you're on the website, you're on facebook. When you're on a mobile app, you're on facebook. You don't perceive a difference between mediums whatsoever. In a similar sense, all 4 of my products need to feel like the same service being accessed rather than 4 distinct entities.

Any advice?

Comment: dmacfour, you've asked a [ton of questions](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/39427/dmacfour?tab=questions&sort=activity) on UX.SE without accepting a single answer.  For most of the question you haven't even bothered to vote on any of the answers.  Before you ask more questions, please go back and consider accepting some of the answers because the community has volunteered quite a bit of time to help you out without acknowledgement on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really broad question, but, in general, these companies invest a whole lot into user experience. And this is way beyond just having a UX team or graphic designer.

Especially at Apple. Apple is a company that essentially sells a user experience. They pretty much start with the user experience and design around that.

Another huge advantage very few companies have that both Apple and Facebook benefit from is having a singular voice...not just in terms of outward appearances, but literally, internally, everything often boils down to one voice. Jony Ive in Apple's case and Zuckerberg in Facebook's case. This is a rare luxury, though, as most companies, alas, have to build experiences with the feedback of dozens of stakeholders which can often lead to design-by-committee.

Your challenge is that you have 4 existing products already. Ideally, UX thinking would have been involved prior to these even being built. At this point, you need to invest in UX. How much you need to invest is really hard to say without knowing the plethora of details regarding your specific products, audience, technology, etc.